# Checking An Immersion Map

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, differential-topology

Let C be the complex numbers. Consider the map  $f: C \rightarrow C \times \mathbb{R}$ given by

$f(z) = (z^2,  \text{Im}(z))$

($\text{Im}(z)$ is the imaginary part of $z$)

a. Is $f$ an immersion?

b. Is the restriction of $f$ to  ${z : 1\le
 |z| \le 2}$ an immersion?

I'm confused about the f here because how would i take the derivative of this map?

Comment: Why not write it out explicitly as a map $\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R^3$ and compute the derivative (Jacobian) matrix? There are fancier approaches, but they are not needed.